GridDB Array Type not showing in GridDB CLI
my GridDB container schema looks like this:
class ConfigInfo {
    @RowKey String logtype;
    String file_path;
    Integer interval;
    Integer expiration_time;
    Integer partition_unit;
    Integer timestamp_position;
    String regex_format;
    String timestamp_format;
    String[] schema;
}

I know my data is being saved properly inside of my container because I can query it and it results in the proper array that I know is in there.
but when I was doing a quick test to check the contents of my container, the array type just reads null in the CLI:
First, the container:
gs[public]> showcontainer configs
Database    : public
Name        : configs
Type        : COLLECTION
Partition ID: 51
DataAffinity: -

Columns:
No  Name                  Type            CSTR  RowKey
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  logtype               STRING          NN    [RowKey]
 1  file_path             STRING
 2  interval              INTEGER
 3  expiration_time       INTEGER
 4  partition_unit        INTEGER
 5  timestamp_position    INTEGER
 6  regex_format          STRING
 7  timestamp_format      STRING
 8  schema                STRING_ARRAY

Indexes:
Name        :
Type        : TREE
Columns:
No  Name
--------------------------
 0  logtype

and then the row itself:
gs[public]> select *  from configs;
1 results. (2 ms)
gs[public]> get
logtype,file_path,interval,expiration_time,partition_unit,timestamp_position,regex_format,timestamp_format,schema
tests,log-half-second.txt,1000,5,10,1,([\w]+\s[\w]+\s[\d]+\s[\d:]+\s[\w]+\s[\w]+\s[\w]+)\s([\w]+)\s(.+),EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss a z YYYY,(NULL)
The 1 results had been acquired.

you can see here that everything seems to work, but the array type comes up as null. but if I query it in my server logic, it works.
I'm assuming this is normal but I can't quite figure it out?
